# WebRTC Perfect Negotiation Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webrtc, getusermedia, rtcpeerconnection

I'm implementing [WebRTC Perfect Negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation) in my Vue 2 application. The app will have multiple viewers and a single streamer.

After a lot of logging and debugging, I've resolved some of the problems that I was having. I removed the TURN server in the `iceServers` configuration, and that allowed the ICE Candidate gathering to finish. Previously it was stuck at "gathering". Now, the two peers have exchanged local/remote descriptions and added ICE candidates, but there still is not a change in the `connectionState`.

Here is my `RTCPeerConnection` object:

```
RTCPeerConnection
canTrickleIceCandidates: true
connectionState: "new"
currentLocalDescription: RTCSessionDescription {type: 'offer', sdp: 'v=0\r\no=- 4764627134364341061 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns…4754 label:f12fee59-268c-4bc3-88c1-8ac27aec8a9c\r\n'}
currentRemoteDescription: RTCSessionDescription {type: 'answer', sdp: 'v=0\r\no=- 3069477756847576830 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns…Nd1pO\r\na=ssrc:1149065622 cname:VquHLgyd/d3Nd1pO\r\n'}
iceConnectionState: "new"
iceGatheringState: "complete"
localDescription: RTCSessionDescription {type: 'offer', sdp: 'v=0\r\no=- 4764627134364341061 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns…4754 label:f12fee59-268c-4bc3-88c1-8ac27aec8a9c\r\n'}
onaddstream: null
onconnectionstatechange: ƒ (e)
ondatachannel: null
onicecandidate: ƒ (_ref)
onicecandidateerror: ƒ (e)
oniceconnectionstatechange: ƒ ()
onicegatheringstatechange: ƒ (e)
onnegotiationneeded: ƒ ()
onremovestream: null
onsignalingstatechange: null
ontrack: ƒ (_ref3)
pendingLocalDescription: null
pendingRemoteDescription: null
remoteDescription: RTCSessionDescription {type: 'answer', sdp: 'v=0\r\no=- 3069477756847576830 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns…Nd1pO\r\na=ssrc:1149065622 cname:VquHLgyd/d3Nd1pO\r\n'}
sctp: null
signalingState: "stable"
[[Prototype]]: RTCPeerConnection
```

Here is `LiveStream.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <main>
      <div>
        <div id="video-container">
          <h2>LiveStream</h2>
          <video id="local-video" ref="localVideo" autoplay="true"></video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <aside>
      <div>
        <div>
          <p>ViewStream</p>
          <div v-for="(item, key) in participants" :key="key">
            <Video :videoId="key" :videoStream="participants[key].peerStream" />
          </div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </aside>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { videoConfiguration } from "../mixins/WebRTC";
import Video from "../components/Video.vue";

export default {
  name: "LiveStream",
  components: {
    Video,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      participants: {},
      localStream: null,
      pc: null,
      roomInfo: {
        room: undefined,
        username: "testUser",
      },
      constraints: {
        video: {
          width: 450,
          height: 348,
        },
      },
    };
  },
  mixins: [videoConfiguration],
  methods: {
    async initializeWebRTC(user, desc) {
      console.log("initializeWebRTC called", { user, desc });
      this.participants[user] = {
        ...this.participants[user],
        pc: this.setupRTCPeerConnection(
          new RTCPeerConnection(this.configuration),
          user,
          this.roomInfo.username,
          this.roomInfo.room
        ),
        peerStream: null,
        peerVideo: null,
      };

      for (const track of this.localStream.getTracks()) {
        this.participants[user].pc.addTrack(track, this.localStream);
        console.log("local track added", track);
      }

      this.createOffer(
        this.participants[user].pc,
        user,
        this.roomInfo.room,
        true
      );

      this.onIceCandidates(
        this.participants[user].pc,
        user,
        this.roomInfo.room,
        true
      );
    },
    createPeerConnection() {
      this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(this.configuration);
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.roomInfo.room = this.getRoomName();
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.myVideo = document.getElementById("local-video");

    await this.getUserMedia();
    await this.getAudioVideo();

    this.$socket.client.emit("joinRoom", {
      ...this.roomInfo,
      creator: true,
    });
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.pc.close();
    this.pc = null;
    this.$socket.$unsubscribe("newParticipant");
    this.$socket.$unsubscribe("onMessage");
    this.$socket.client.emit("leaveRoom", {
      to: this.to,
      from: this.username,
      room: this.roomInfo.room,
    });
  },
  sockets: {
    connect() {
      console.log("connected socket");
    },
    newParticipant(userObject) {
      if (userObject.username === this.roomInfo.username) return;
      this.$set(this.participants, userObject.username, {
        user: userObject.username,
      });
      this.initializeWebRTC(userObject.username);
    },
    async onMessage({ desc, from, room, candidate }) {
      if (from === this.username) return;
      try {
        if (desc) {
          const offerCollision =
            desc.type === "offer" &&
            (this.makingOffer ||
              this.participants[from].pc.signalingState !== "stable");

          this.ignoreOffer = !this.isPolitePeer && offerCollision;
          if (this.ignoreOffer) {
            return;
          }

          if (desc.type === "offer") {
            this.handleAnswer(desc, this.participants[from].pc, from, room);
          } else {
            this.addRemoteTrack(this.participants[from], from);
            await this.setRemoteDescription(desc, this.participants[from].pc);
          }
        } else if (candidate) {
          try {
            await this.addCandidate(
              this.participants[from].pc,
              candidate.candidate
            );
          } catch (err) {
            if (!this.ignoreOffer) {
              throw err;
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Here is the mixin I created to handle a lot of the connection functionality:

```js
export const videoConfiguration = {
  data() {
    return {
      // Media config
      constraints: {
        audio: {
          echoCancellation: true,
          noiseSuppression: true,
          autoGainControl: false
        },
        video: {
          width: 400,
          height: 250
        }
      },
      configuration: {
        iceServers: [
          {
            urls: [
              "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
              "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      offerOptions: {
        offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
        offerToReceiveVideo: 1
      },
      myVideo: null,
      localStream: null,
      username: null,
      isPolitePeer: false,
      makingOffer: false,
      ignoreOffer: false
    };
  },
  async created() {
    this.username = await this.getUsername();
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * Get permission to read from user's microphone and camera.
     * Returns audio and video streams to be added to video element
     */
    async getUserMedia() {
      if ("mediaDevices" in navigator) {
        try {
          const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
            this.constraints
          );

          if ("srcObject" in this.myVideo) {
            this.myVideo.srcObject = stream;
            this.myVideo.volume = 0;
          } else {
            this.myVideo.src = stream;
          }
          this.localStream = stream;
        } catch (error) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
    },
    getAudioVideo() {
      const video = this.localStream.getVideoTracks();
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(video);
      const audio = this.localStream.getAudioTracks();
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
      console.log(audio);
    },
    async setRemoteDescription(remoteDesc, pc) {
      try {
        await pc.setRemoteDescription(remoteDesc);
      } catch (error) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
    addCandidate(pc, candidate) {
      try {
        const rtcIceCandidate = new RTCIceCandidate(candidate);
        pc.addIceCandidate(rtcIceCandidate);
        console.log(`${this.username} added a candidate`);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(
          `Error adding a candidate in ${this.username}. Error: ${error}`
        );
      }
    },
    onIceCandidates(pc, to, room) {
      pc.onicecandidate = ({ candidate }) => {
        if (!candidate) return;

        this.$socket.client.emit("new-ice-candidate", {
          candidate,
          to: to,
          from: this.username,
          room: room
        });
      };
    },
    async createOffer(pc, to, room) {
      console.log(`${this.roomInfo.username} wants to start a call with ${to}`);

      pc.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
        try {
          this.makingOffer = true;
          await pc.setLocalDescription();
          this.sendSignalingMessage(pc.localDescription, true, to, room);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } finally {
          this.makingOffer = false;
        }
      };
    },
    async createAnswer(pc, to, room) {
      try {
        const answer = await pc.createAnswer();
        await pc.setLocalDescription(answer);
        this.sendSignalingMessage(pc.localDescription, false, to, room);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    },
    async handleAnswer(desc, pc, from, room) {
      await this.setRemoteDescription(desc, pc);
      this.createAnswer(pc, from, room);
    },
    sendSignalingMessage(desc, offer, to, room) {
      const isOffer = offer ? "offer" : "answer";
      // Send the offer to the other peer
      if (isOffer === "offer") {
        this.$socket.client.emit("offer", {
          desc: desc,
          to: to,
          from: this.username,
          room: room,
          offer: isOffer
        });
      } else {
        this.$socket.client.emit("answer", {
          desc: desc,
          to: to,
          from: this.username,
          room: room,
          offer: isOffer
        });
      }
    },
    addRemoteTrack(user, video) {
      user.peerVideo = user.peerVideo || document.getElementById(video);
      user.pc.ontrack = ({ track, streams }) => {
        user.peerStream = streams[0];
        track.onunmute = () => {
          if (user.peerVideo.srcObject) {
            return;
          }
          user.peerVideo.srcObject = streams[0];
        };
      };
    },
    /**
     * Using handleRemoteTrack temporarily to add the tracks to the RTCPeerConnection
     * for ViewStream since the location of pc is different.
     * @param {*} user
     */
    handleRemoteTrack(pc, user) {
      this.peerVideo = document.getElementById(user);
      pc.ontrack = ({ track, streams }) => {
        this.peerStream = streams[0];
        track.onunmute = () => {
          if (this.peerVideo.srcObject) {
            return;
          }
          this.peerVideo.srcObject = streams[0];
        };
      };
    },
    setupRTCPeerConnection(pc) {
      pc.onconnectionstatechange = (e) => {
        console.log(
          "WebRTC: Signaling State Updated: ",
          e.target.signalingState
        );
      };

      pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
        console.log("WebRTC: ICE Connection State Updated");
      };

      pc.onicegatheringstatechange = (e) => {
        console.log(
          "WebRTC: ICE Gathering State Updated: ",
          e.target.iceGatheringState
        );
      };

      pc.onicecandidateerror = (e) => {
        if (e.errorCode === 701) {
          console.log("ICE Candidate Error: ", e);
        }
      };

      return pc;
    }
  }
};
```

I created a CodeSandbox that has the `ViewStream.vue` file and the directory structure for how I'm trying to set it up. (It's just too much code to post here.)

[image: Edit misty-cdn-etmi0f]

- When the viewer joins the room created by the streamer, I can see that they exchange offer/answer and ice candidates. However, I still do not see any change in the `connectionState` or `iceConnectionState`. Is there a piece that I'm not doing?
- One thing I noticed when logging data and digging through chrome://webrtc-internals/ is that the `MediaStream` ID's don't match.
  I log out the tracks after the call to `getUserMedia()`, and note the track ID's.

This image shows the stream IDs for the caller (top) and the callee (bottom)

[image: Calls to getUserMedia()]

I then log when I'm adding the local tracks to the `RTCPeerConnection`, and they match what was generated for both peers.

Here, the tracks for the streamer are added to the `RTCPeerConnection`. The IDs match from above.

[image: Tracks for streamer in LiveStream]

However, I'm also logging for each peer when I receive a remote track, and that's when the ID's don't match.

I don't know what is generating the ID in this picture. It's different from the ID of the callee in the first picture.

[image: Track from remote peer]

Is that normal behavior? Would the fact that the IDs don't match be the cause of the streams not starting on either end? I don't know what would cause this. The IDs are the same when added to the `RTCPeerConnection` on either end of the call.

Edit 5/1: I removed the TURN server from my config, and that fixed part of the connection process. Still having a problem getting media to flow between peers. But I can see that I've captured a `MediaStream` on each side of the connection.

Comment: I believe that once you set the `srcObject` to your `video` tag - you should also call `myVideo.play()` to start the stream.

Comment: I updated `onAddStream` to include:
```javascript
user.peerVideo.play();
```

But it still doesn't play the video. I've updated the code in the question to reflect this addition.

Comment: yes, I saw the autoplay attribute in the video tag, So, I guess you don't need to explicitly do video.play() btw, could you please share the server side code so that I can recreate whats going on?

Comment: @Darkcheftar I apologize I missed the second part of your message. I've added the server code in the CodeSandbox in a file called `server.js`.

Comment: From what you are saying, I don't think that it is a track playing problem, but a connection one, in order to send a track the peers should be in the connected state

Comment: @Skin_phil That's a good callout. I didn't know to consider that. What causes the `connectionState` to change? I thought it was something that happened after I had both the localDescription and remoteDescription set, but clearly that's not the case. Do I need to implement an `onconnectionstatechange` handler?

Comment: Not really you just need to be sure that you are exchanging ice candidates correctly, i found out that that is one of the main reasons why peers do not go into connected state

Comment: I can see that the peer that is initiating the call is sending ice candidates to the other peer (the callee). And I'm calling `addIceCandidate` to add it to the `RTCPeerConnection` object for the callee. What causes the callee to generate ice candidates? Is it `createAnswer()`, or `setRemoteDescription()`. That part isn't clear.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69539715/when-rtcpeerconnection-onicecandidate-event-get-invoked/69600289#69600289) addresses one of my questions above. Setting `localDescription` triggers ice candidates whether it was an offer or answer being set.

Comment: I don't know if this can help you, but I wrote this guide after I had to set up a react app with WebRTC: https://cesarepolonara.com/blog/posts/1FvO2fYBsp156YuHKFLk6o

Comment: @CesarePolonara Thank you! Your guide seems very comprehensive. I'll go through and see where my setup could be better. I can't shake this feeling that I'm close, there's just something that's not quite right that's jamming me up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `connectionState` is not updating. There maybe a race condition between creating the offer and answer that is not allowing `connectionState` to update.

You may want see look into adding a promise on creating the offer and answer, and on when the ice candidates are completed to handle this race condition.

Answer (score 0):

Can I have the Server side code? So that I can recreate whats going on?

Edit:
[image: An important thing to keep in mind is this: the roles of caller and callee can switch during perfect negotiation.]

If you are talking about this in your second question.

I guess it just explains how the collision between a polite and impolite peer is resolved by polite peer becoming callee from caller.

And that is just the definition of `Polite Peer` and I thing you don't need to worry much about explicitly changing the roles in this context.

`A polite peer, essentially, is one which may send out offers, but then responds if an offer arrives from the other peer with "Okay, never mind, drop my offer and I'll consider yours instead.` ~ [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Perfect_negotiation)

I hope this answers your Second Question

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

I was getting this error: `TypeError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The provided value is not of type 'RTCIceCandidateInit'.`

Googling that led me to [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908081/webrtc-getting-failed-to-execute-addicecandidate-on-rtcpeerconnection-error-on) which led me to believe that it was an error that I could safely ignore.

However, the MDN docs said that I'd get a TypeError if I was missing a required part of the object, and that led me to realize that on both sides of the call I was destructuring `{candidate}`, passing in an incomplete object. So the candidates that were being passed to each party weren't really being added. Once I fixed that everything worked.